# Contractor does not apply agreed reimbursements to his subcontractor

Tags: construction-law

I have mobile payment app record of a payment to a general contractor. It is tagged as

> Reimburse for TheSubcontractor'

The general contractor has already paid TheSubcontractor.

I discovered during a conversation with the general contractor that they actually paid a sizeable fraction less than the amount to TheSubcontractor. To me that's a serious deal - I would label that as a misappropriation of funds.  Surprisingly the contractor does not dispute the disparity but also has no intentions on paying the Subcontractor the difference.

While I realize that home renovation / construction can  be wild and woolly this seems a bit pointedly so.   I'm not sure what a typical/appropriate way to consider handling this would be.

Comment: Was the subcontractor happy with the amount and has he given you a lien waiver? General contractors will charge subcontractor's bill + overhead so that's valid.

Comment: The agreement was no surcharges on labor and materials.